# Error validating access token: Session is invalid. This could be because the application was uninstalled after the session was created

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have published an android app integrating with Facebook SDK 3.0. but implementing the login to Facebook via the authorize method, handling SSO as well.

I'm getting from my users the following Facebook error:

"Error validating access token: Session is
invalid. This could be because the application was uninstalled after the session was created"

not sure I understand why this error appears and what does it means?

How can I reproduce this error? what is the scenario and is it common?

Answer (score 1):

This error means that after the user authorized your app, they went to their [facebook account settings](https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications) and removed your app. In this case, your app needs the user to authorize it again.

You should also check out [this page](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/errors/) which explains how to handle different errors, as well as the Scrumptious sample app, which gives you an idea of how to handle them in code.

Comment: When reproducing the flow as you mentioned, i get the following error: "Error validating access token: User xxxxxxxx has not authorized application yyyyyyyyyy." and not the error message i described.

Comment: do you have an open session at this time? Has the user authorized your application before? It's possible that the access token has expired, or the user on your device changed. Try doing a session.closeAndClearTokenInformation (or remove your app from the device and reinstall it), and redo the authorization flow again.  If you get any further errors, any code snippets or providing the actual error code/sub code would help.

Comment: I'm using the authorize method and not the "Sessions" method. before each authorize i do a request "/me" check to Facebook to verify the connection to Facebook. after the login to Facebook is completed i saved the user's name and token. when i get the described error the user name is not saved, meaning that there was an error during the login process itself.

Comment: If there was an error during the login process, you wouldn't get a token to save. This error in particular means exactly what I said in the answer (in that the user authorized you app, but then deleted the app from the facebook website, and then tried to use your app again with the FB connection, which is why the token is now invalid). You can explicitly handle this in your code by looking at the error code, and asking them to reauthorize (delete the saved token, and go through the authorize flow again). Also, if you're using 3.0 of the SDK, you should really use the new Session mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

@Jon : I think you have to maintain the client session and store the accesstoken in the session. When client try to interact with FB then use this accessToken again.

After sometime this accessToken will be invalidate by FB api, hence you need to get new one and store it again.